# What is going on with two equals operators?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at this arrangement:

```
if trie.nil?
  trie = @hash[letter] = Trie.new(@level + 1)
end
```

and interpreting it, starting from the right, as:

1. Create a new instance from the `Trie` class with the appropriate arguments.
2. That instance becomes a value in the `@hash` hash, and it is indexed by the `letter` key.
3. That instance is also stored in the variable `trie`, so it can be used elsewhere.

How close did I get? Are instances of `Trie` tables really stored in hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

`Trie.new(@level + 1)` is created, the value returned and assigned to `@hash[letter]` that in turns return the same value and it is assigned to `trie.`

At the end of the execution, both `trie` and `@hash[letter]` will point to the same newly created instance of `Trie`.

The multiple assignment is common in case you are creating a new object, you need to cache it somewhere (for example for memoization), but at the same time you need to reuse the variable in the same method and you want to use a shortcut.

Let's say 3 lines later in the same scope you need to use the newly created object. You could access the object as `@hash[letter]` but `trie` is shorter. Of course, this is just one of the possible usages.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the logic isn't clear. The use of two assignments on a single line is a maintenance problem in waiting.

Instead, it'd be clearer, and more idiomatic, to write the code in two lines:

```
trie = Trie.new(@level + 1) if trie.nil?
@hash[letter] = trie
```

or:

```
trie ||= Trie.new(@level + 1)
@hash[letter] = trie
```

The second example uses `||=` to check to see if `trie` is initialized, i.e., not nil. If it is not nil the code falls through. If it *is* nil, then `trie` will be assigned the value of a new instance of Trie. And, in all cases, `@hash[letter]` gets assigned the current value of `trie`.

This is a great example of what happens when someone tries to be macho in code. *THEY* understand what they're doing but they leave everyone else scratching their head, and wondering two different things:

- WHAT is that doing?!
- WHY DID THEY DO THAT!?

In a code-review neither is a good thing to hear, so write your code as if someone else will be reading it further down the road, because, odds are good someone will -- either it'll be you, or whoever gets to maintain your code -- so be kind.

Comment: Thanks! I like hearing that things I don't understand are not up to scratch.

Comment: It's a hard lesson to learn that our inability to understand something *might* be because it really is screwed up. Most of us try to puzzle our way through it to understand how come we don't understand, when really it might be the other person, or their example, that's all FUBAR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

From right to left every chunk of code is executed before the assignment

Example:

```
variable = nil
hash = {}

variable = hash[:key] = String.new("text")

variable #=> "text"
hash     #=> {:key => "text"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, multiple assignment is right associative. The reason for this is that the left side of an assignment construction has to be a single literal token: In assignment `foo = bar`, `bar` may be of an arbitrary complexity, but `foo` must be a single token; It makes sense to assign some complex expression to a single name, but it does not make sense to assign something to a complex expression. So if you have `a = b = c`, then `a = (b = c)` is the only way to make sense out of it, and that is the way Ruby works.

Regarding your concern that keeping a table as a hash value may be perhaps too large an object, it does not matter because all that is kept is just a pointer to the object.